# lazarus-Error compiling a database driven program in lazarus

Tags: lazarus, delphi

I am trying to create a program using the postgresql database with lazarus.

I got the following error in compiling:

`registersqldb.pas(72,3) Fatal: Can not find unit mysql55conn used by registersqldb.`

what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project was probably created with a development version of FPC. (2.7.1 or 2.6.1), and you are probably trying to compile it with a stock release (2.6.0) version.

Solution: install a 2.6.1 based lazarus snapshot, or change the program to use an older mysql library.

I would recommend against 2.7.1 based snapshots. Too much is broken atm.

Disclaimer: I don't use mysql, so don't know exact compatibility details between versions, except that it is not always easy.

Comment: 2.6.2RC1 is available. Grab it :-)